# Inserting data from Text file into Mssql database using Python and pymssql

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, pymssql

I have this following code which I am trying to use and insert data from a text file to a database that has a table named "newTable" (It has 2 columns namely lineNumber and text). I am unable to get the data in the database as well as getting error that states

```
"ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near ')'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")"
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
I did refer to various questions which are identical, but the solutions didn't work for me.

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open("textfile.txt",encoding  = "utf-8" ))
f=open("textfile.txt", encoding  = "utf-8")
lines=f.readlines()
print(lines)
i=1
while i<=num_lines:
    time = (lines[i])
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO newTable (LineNumber, Text) VALUES (%d, %s)", (i, time, ))
    conn.commit()
    i+=1
```

Comment: When using [`executemany`](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.Cursor.executemany), the second parameter must be a sequence of tuples. Your example looks very much like you pass just a single tuple to it. In this context (while iterating over the lines of the file), you probably meant to use [`execute`](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.Cursor.execute) instead.

Comment: @shmee, Thank you. It worked!